# Is it possible to try more than one XPATH? PYTHON SELENIUM

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to figure out if it were possible to try more than one xpaths until it finds the correct one. I need this because the page im trying to scrape has different xpaths per question. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

It is. You can define the list of your x paths, as strings.

```
    List<String> listOfStringsXpath= new ArrayList<String>();
    listOfStringsXpath.add ("xpath string 1");
    listOfStringsXpath.add ("xpath string 2");
    ....
    WebElement we = null;
    for(int i =0;i<listOfStringsXpath.size();i++){
      
    if(driver.findelements(By.xpath(listOfStringsXpath.get(i))).size()>0)
    {
       we = driver.findelements(By.xpath(listOfStringsXpath.get(i))).get(0);
       break;
    }
    // use "we" as your found web element, but first check is it null
}
```

this is a Java solution, but you can use exacly same logic for python.